# Laravel Socialite error: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."

Tags: php, facebook, laravel, laravel-5, facebook-php-sdk

I'm using `Socialite` to authenticate my users via Facebook. However, I can't get it to work. I followed [this](https://blog.damirmiladinov.com/laravel/laravel-5.2-socialite-facebook-login.html#.WElpIfnhCUk) tutorial, but I get the following error:

[image]

I looked everywhere and tried whatever, but I can't get it to work. Here's my code:

In services.php:

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => '[My App ID]',
    'client_secret' => '[My App Secret]',
    'redirect' => 'http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback/',
],
```

My routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web', 'requestlog']], function () {   
    Route::get('auth/facebook', 'Auth\AuthController@redirectToProvider');
    Route::get('auth/facebook/callback/', 'Auth\AuthController@handleProviderCallback');
});
```

Then in my AuthController:

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;

public function redirectToProvider()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallback()
{
    try {

        $providerUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();
        dd('yay it worked!');

      } catch (RequestException $e) {

      dd($e->getResponse()->json());

    }
}
```

Then I have these settings in FB:

[image]

[image]

What is going wrong? I followed all the necessary steps as far as I know. I don't get what's wrong here. I hope I provided all the necessary information!

**Edit**

Here's what the url looks like on the page where the error displays:
`http://localhost:8000/auth/facebook/callback?code=AQBtnKEqZgImLqN7f3hETe9GptgzFH71sXrV5qmv8Rpo6Oj5-4rl8mBjFPbfkBtiV8w9atV7X4OrWfHyalJkXU-k6lkEv1bly6v5Qxm2es-_RRp8gfoSWOZwjqE34Rvq6__L3aEOERPEa9LSBk_rKVP_cYGZoQeAydRLQUZVGdr_p1SuE1hRZIvZTAZ-zorkPoyyCDNZtDEVFHGRJt_c3kTf_AKE97FVemrXrUDzxaX-rvovKtfGF3u4CvAIt5pe4g7zD30jAWF78ZgjjPpr21MdaGwP5V0tc8g84oz0dR5Nbit7sKeUE-XblWFrQCIKfqs-OJ6rcuzw7iPTx6xrQ9Ev&state=4f924a9974207482c6fce24c1d74705c6688adc0#_=_`

I also tried in incognito mode, removed cookies and so on. Same result...

Comment: Maybe the token is expired, try if you rerequest the token if it works.

Comment: @BartBergmans do you mean the app secret refreshing? If that's not what you mean, then how can I rerequest that token you're talking about? I'm fairly new to this, hope you can help! By the way, I already tried in incognito if that helps.

Comment: What will return in this `$providerUser = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();`?

Comment: @Markinson `$providerUser` return `null`?

Comment: @KelvinKyaw The exception gets thrown at `Socialite::driver('facebook')->user()` so `$providerUser` isn't even ever set at all

Comment: Can you try to do this in incognito mode? also revoke the access to your app for you facebook user and redo the login process. You are actually being redirected right? Do you get a token in the url when being redirected? Try to manually get the access token using the returned token.

Comment: @FrankProvost I tried in incognito, and deleted the app at my facebook profile. I did an update in my post with a little more info. Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can take that code that is returned in the url and try to get an access token with it manually.

Comment: @FrankProvost That is possible indeed, but I still wonder why it doesn't work the Laravel-way for me...

Comment: I'm sadly out of ideas. A good month ago i simply followed the steps from the official laravel docs and everythig worked fine for me. Only suggestion is to quickly setup a fresh laravel installation and try to use the laravel docs instead of the tut to get it running.

Comment: @FrankProvost I reïnstalled the entire Socialite package and everything that comes with it and I think i solved the problem! Explained my solution in an answer if you're interested :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't want to mess with access tokens or other API's because I don't think that would be a solution to my problem. But now (after I don't know how long...) I got it to work! For whoever has this problem as well; I did the following steps which out of luck made it work:

1. I deleted socialite from composer.json and updated it.
2. I reinstalled socialite. I added the following line in composer.json: `"laravel/socialite": "2.*"`.
3. Then when I ran the snippet I got the following error: `ErrorException in FacebookProvider.php line 89:Undefined index: first_name`.
4. After that I replaced the code in `FacebookProvider.php`  [with this file from github](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/laravel/socialite/master/src/Two/FacebookProvider.php).

Don't forget to execute random `composer dump-autoload`'s everytime because sometimes that randomly seems to help as well.

Now it finally works for whatever reason!

**EDIT**

I also noticed that `composer update` does a good job. Update socialite to the newest version if this doesn't work. This eventually fixed another problem I had recently.

Comment: Thanks alot, it saved my life :)

Comment: @MahaDev glad it did! :-)

Answer (score 5):

Running `composer update` and then `composer dump-autoload` solved the issue for me.

I noticed Laravel Socialite was updated, so @Markinson is right

Comment: Indeed for me the same, `laravel/socialite (v2.0.20 => v2.0.21):`

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked with `composer require laravel/socialite:2.0.21` ... upgrade from 2.0.20